# Get Roster List XMPP Framework

Tags: ios, ejabberd, xmppframework

Following is the delegate method I have used and even though it gets called, '***queryElement***' is assigned a **nil** value. Though the logged in user has many contacts.

```
-(BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
   NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
   NSMutableArray *ArrayUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   if (queryElement) 
   {
       NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
       [ArrayUsers removeAllObjects];
       for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) 
       {
           NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
           [ArrayUsers addObject:jid];
       }
   }
   NSLog(@"users: %@",ArrayUsers);
   return NO;

}
```

Any one who could help getting buddy's list (both online and offline)?

XMPPFramework's method:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
```

is called everytime a buddy comes online or goes offline. But a complete list of buddies is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get full roster list, you need to send a roster request:

```
- (void)FetchFriends 
{
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>"error:&error];
    NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];

    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"ANY_ID_NAME"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"ANY_ID_NAME@weejoob.info"];
    [iq addChild:query];

    [xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}
```

Server responds to request, and the response is treated by following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
    if (queryElement) 
    {
        NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
        for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Friend: %@",[[itemElements[i] attributeForName:@"jid"]stringValue]);
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The rosters may contain, type of relationship (to, none, both, from), based on your requirement you may choose the appropriate roster members by 'type' attribute of above item list.

Comment: where to implement  {- (void)FetchFriends } method

Comment: @ChanchalRaj how to set that both.I am able to get the Both users But how to send the subscription some times i'm not getting both it is showing as from

Comment: the `didReceiveIQ` delegate method is never being called for me. I used your code exactly only thing I did is translate it to swift

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 5:**

```
func fetchFreind(){
        let query = try? DDXMLElement(xmlString:"<query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>")
        let iq =  DDXMLElement(name: "iq")
        iq.addAttribute(withName:"type" , stringValue: "get")
        iq.addAttribute(withName:"id" , stringValue: "ANY_ID_NAME")
        iq.addAttribute(withName:"from" , stringValue: "ANY_ID_NAME@aaa")
        iq.addChild(query!)
        xmppStream.send(iq)
    }
```

**And you get list :**

```
 func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive iq: XMPPIQ!) -> Bool {
        let queryElement = iq.elements(forName:"query")
        if queryElement.count > 0{
            let itemElement = queryElement[0].elements(forName: "item")
            for item in itemElement{
                print("User JID :- \(String(describing: item.attribute(forName: "jid")!))")
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```